# How to delete files in S3 using CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I have created a CodePipeline that takes input(files) from CodeCommit repository and deploys files to S3 bucket. When I delete files in CodeCommit repository, pipeline doesn't delete the file in the corresponding S3 bucket. In short, I want my S3 bucket to be in sync with CodeCommit repository. How can I achieve this?

My Pipeline doesn't have CodeBuild stage.

AWS-CodeCommit --> CodePipeline --> Deploy-to-Cross-Account-S3

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, currently there is no predefined configuration of an S3 Deploy action to delete an S3 object from the pipeline itself.

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#w299aac41c11c11c25b3)

The workaround for now will be to add another action on the pipeline to use CodeBuild to perform the objects cleanup before/after deploying them.

Comment: So I guess this means adding a Build stage that just deletes all the files in the s3 bucket deploy location. I noticed that CodePipeline replaces all the existing objects, the deleted objects (which are still in the bucket) have an older timestamp. So the Build stage can be `aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/deploy-path/deployment --recursive`, and then the deployment will write all the current objects there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CodeBuild stage of:

```
      - aws s3 sync . s3://[bucket_name] --delete
```

Not sure how to make it work cross-account, tho.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom AWS construct to replace S3DeployAction to deploy to S3 and delete old files. The construct diffs the changes using a lambda function to delete old files and upload new files to S3.

To use it just replace `S3DeployAction` with `S3SyncDeployAction`.

```js
import { S3SyncDeployAction } from "@monim67/s3-sync-deploy-action";

const deployAction = new S3SyncDeployAction({
  actionName: 'S3Deploy',
  bucket: targetBucket,
  input: sourceOutput,
});
```

See installation and usage details of the Typescript construct [here](https://github.com/monim67/s3-sync-deploy-action).