# AWS Codepipeline Deploy to S3 with a --delete flag

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

AWS Codepipeline supports [deploying to S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-deploying-to-amazon-s3/).

I have an Angular SPA that I'm deploying to S3 as a static website (using Cloudfront, etc)

When I do the `ng build --prod` command, I include [`outputHashing`](https://angular.io/cli/build), which will change the file names deployed over time.

However when deploying to S3 in my Codepipeline, it's not removing *old* js/css files with different hashes, but continually adding new files

I'd like to use Codepipeline to deploy to S3 with the same behavior as

```sh
aws s3 sync ./dist s3://mywebsite-bucket.com/ --acl public-read --delete
```

Note the `--delete` flag.

Is this possible to set up in Codepipeline when deploying to S3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete files in S3 using CodePipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188543/how-to-delete-files-in-s3-using-codepipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a similar set-up, as s3 deployment with --delete is *currently not possible*. Instead, see bash commands below, use a codebuild stage for deployment in the codepipeline.

```
echo "Syncing directory files to s3"
aws s3 sync ./dist s3://mywebsite-bucket.com/ \
--grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers \
--delete
```

*Note, grants command will achieve same outcome as --acl public-read.*

Comment: I understand this, the question was how to get this effect in codepipeline when S3 is the [deployment provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-s3deploy.html). It it's _not_ possible, I'll definitely revert to using codebuild in the way you show in the answer

Comment: Ah apologies i missed the bit where you only wanted to use s3 as your deployment option. Correct, this is not possible as the deployment uses essentially a cp instead of sync --delete. With no current additional configurations allowed to delete. But what is the structure of your pipeline? As to achieve what your after you'll need to do a build prior to deploying if your going to execute the cli commands. --updated answer to reflect